# Android Media Player does not stop (live stream url)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a service to play sound.

I'm trying to stop the sound when I receive a call but I can't.

I want to stop the sound when I receive a call and replay when it ends.

Someone know what I did wrong?

**This is my Service code:**

```
public class MyMediaPlayer extends Service implements OnInfoListener, OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    public static MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    public static String START_PLAY = "START_PLAY";

    IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    MusicServicePhoneStateListener mPhoneListener;

    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = AC.PACKAGE_NAME+".ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG";
    Intent intent;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        /*public MyMediaPlayer getServerInstance() {
            return MyMediaPlayer.this;
        }*/
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        mPhoneListener = new MusicServicePhoneStateListener();
        ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
    }//onCreate


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(START_PLAY, false)) {
            initializePlayer();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    public void initializePlayer() {

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("rtsp://example.com/file.stream");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MyMediaPlayer", "Error");
        }
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

    }



    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
        startMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                // resume playback
                if (mMediaPlayer == null) initializePlayer();
                else if (!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.start();
                mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
                stopMediaPlayer();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
                // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
                // is likely to resume
                pauseMediaPlayer();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
                // at an attenuated level
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        stopMediaPlayer();
        ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer player, int what, int extra) {

        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED || what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_TIMED_OUT || extra == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_IO) {
            Log.e("MediaPlayer","Error");
        }

        stopMediaPlayer();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        return false;
    }

    public void startMediaPlayer() {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void pauseMediaPlayer() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public void stopMediaPlayer() {
        if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
        Log.d("MediaPlayer","stop()");
    }


    private class MusicServicePhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

        private boolean mResumeAfterCall = false;

        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incoming_number) {
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    mResumeAfterCall = mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
                    stopMediaPlayer();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    if (mMediaPlayer == null && mResumeAfterCall) initializePlayer();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I do not understand why pause() and stop() are not working :(

I have put stopMediaPlayer(); on `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK || TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING` and initializePlayer(); on `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` an this work, but I do not know why not work with stop() or pause().

Comment: Tried to debug.. ?? Was mMediaPlayer.stop(); functaion called..?

Comment: I receive: `V/MediaPlayer﹕ stop` but the sound does not stop :( And after the call I receive an error: `E/MediaPlayer﹕ start called in state 64`

Answer (score 0):

You can try a some hack.

- Remember current play progress with [getCurrentPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#getCurrentPosition())
- Execute [release()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release())
- When you need to resume playing you need open stream again and rewing to last remember position by [seekTo(int ms)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int))

### 64 state explanation :

> It's the 'stopped' state. When in that state, you need to call
> prepare() again before starting playback.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ssh but I wonder if I can use getCurrentPosition() and seekTo(int ms) with a live stream. My app stopped when I tried that.

Comment: Media Player does not stop

Comment: @user5195185 what actually happens? MediaPlayer doesn't stop or app is stopped?